# matlab iteration with else statement error (output argument)

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I am trying to complete the code below which is an iteration code. Yes I finally got it to work, but when i put the stipulations in for the flag, found and the bottom.

I now get "Output argument "error" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "jacobi"."

I know it has to do with the else statement when flag=0 instead of 1 because everything was working fine until I tried to put the else coding in and now
i get this error. Any help would be very much appreciated.

when i step into the code it works all the way with correct answers and matrix
values. When i am in the final if statment for if flag=1 it will skip down to the else section, print out everything that i want it to print out and then
when the green arrow goes to the final end statment with the function and i click next, it gives off the error above.

how can it work all the way until the final end statement. I have to be missing
something. I am new to this so forgive me if this is something easy.

```
function [x error niter flag ] =jacobi(A,x,b,maxiter, tol)


if isrow(x)==1
   x=x';
end

if isrow(b)==1
   b=b';
end

if n ~= m               
   disp('The matrix has to be square for this function, please enter a 
   matrix that is sqaure');
end



index=1;
Dinv= inv(diag(diag(A)));
D=diag(diag(A));
flag=0;
y=x;

while index <= maxiter 
    z = Dinv*((D-A)*y+b);
       if norm(z-y)<tol
           flag=1;
           err=abs(norm(z-y));
        break
    end
  y=z;
  index=index+1;
end 


if flag==1
   niter=index;
   x=z;
   error=err;
else
    maxindex='you have reached the maximum iterations of %d which is larger 
    than %d.';
         niter=index;
         maxiter=maxiter;
         sprintf(maxindex,niter,maxiter);
end






end
```

Comment: When `flag` is 0, you are not assigning anything to `error`, so the function doesn't know what to give as that output. And you have to change the name of that variable, `error` is a saved word and can cause unpredicted behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you specify an output of:

```
[x error niter flag ]
```

but if you go into the else statement, you are not defining, `x` nor `error`, thus it cannot output these variables. Note that not setting `x` does technically not yield and error as you get it as input, but then the output `x` is equal the input `x`.

Personally I would prefer a version which casts a warning:

```
niter=index;
x=z;
error=err;
if flag==0
    warning(strcat('You have reached the maximum iterations of , int2str(niter),' which is larger than ',int2str(maxiter)));
end
```

instead of

```
if flag==1
   niter=index;
   x=z;
   error=err;
else
    maxindex='you have reached the maximum iterations of %d which is larger 
    than %d.';
    niter=index;
    maxiter=maxiter;
    x=z;
    error=err;
    sprintf(maxindex,niter,maxiter);
end
```

Comment: `x` is not a problem, he gets it as an input.

Comment: Well, error-wise you are right, but I suppose it is still not the x-value that he wants to return, thus I mentioned it.

Comment: thank you all. Yes, I am aware of the error issue, and the changes would be great, but I unfortunately have been given this task and that output is required. Thank you as now I at least do not get that error. i changed the last part to this but do not get the string anymore

Comment: the code i have now is `if flag==1
       niter=index;
       x=z;
       error=err;
      else
    x='N/A';
         error='N/A';
         maxindex='you have reached the maximum iterations of %d which 
        is 
         larger than %d.';
         niter=index;
         maxiter=maxiter;
        sprintf(maxindex,niter,maxiter);
        end`

Comment: I cannot get the code to be formatted correct for this comment.